# QODBC connection string

Tags: php, connection

I am trying to connect to Quickbooks via a php script running on IIS which is running remotely. The issue is that it is not connecting and I am getting this error when I connect with a 32 bit DSN.

> PHP Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
>   Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between
>   the Driver and Application, SQL state IM014 in SQLConnect in
>   D:\www\QBs\index.php on line 7

This is the connection string

```
$rConnection = odbc_connect("QuickBooks Data QRemote","Admin","somepassword");
```

or

```
$rConnection = odbc_connect("QuickBooks Data QRemote","","");
```

When I try the 64 bit connection string it connects but I get an error on the QRemote for QuickBooks - Server that says

> Connection error.Closing socket 02452D68

This is the connection string:

```
$rConnection = odbc_connect("QuickBooks Data 64-Bit QRemote","","");
```

Comment: I did not continue using this approach above i used the QuickBooks web connector approach from here https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

This means either you have 32 bit php and connecting to 64-bit driver or have 64 bit php and connecting to 32 bit driver.

http://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/2439/0/qodbc-reports-architecture-mismatch-problem-when-connecting

For PHP, please follow steps from
http://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/2510

http://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/2623/0/how-to-use-qodbc-with-php

"Connection error.Closing socket 02452D68",  Please refer QODBC Logs.
I guess you might not have QuickBooks running.  Please keep QuickBooks running, login as Admin to your company file and try again.

If you are still facing issue, please raise a support ticket at http://support.qodbc.com

Please share following information when raising support ticket.

1) Screenshot of QODBC Setup Screen -- > About    (Start>>All Programs>> QODBC Driver for use with QuickBooks>> QODBC Setup Screen >> About Tab )

2) Screenshot of the issue you’re facing.

3) SQL Statement having issue

4) Screenshot of the application having issue

5) Sample code (if any, as attachment)
Log Files from

6) QODBC Setup Screen -- > Messages -- > Review QODBC Messages (as attachment)

7) QODBC Setup Screen -- > Messages -- > Review SDK Messages  (as attachment)

Refer : How to take screenshot : http://www.qodbc.com/links/screenshot.htm

Comment: I did not continue using this approach above i used the QuickBooks web connector approach from here https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php and it worked. Thank you